# Snapping not working correctly in object mode

Tags: snapping, object-mode

So, I'm having this problem that I'm sure is just some setting that I'm missing but I'm not able to find anything about it. So when I want to align the rotation of an object with the angle of another object (while keeping the object rotation) I usually do the following: I snap the object-to-rotate to the target object with closest. Then I set the origin in the vertex I want to align and the 3D Cursor to the vertex that is already snapped to the target object. Then I change the pivot point to 3D Cursor, turn snapping on, face mode, active and set it also to rotate. Then I just rotate on an axis and it usually snaps correctly. The problem is that depending on I-don't-know-what some files are set like that and some aren't.

I hope the explanation was clear, I know it's a bit complicated. I uploaded a quick vid to youtube showing my problem (https://youtu.be/eE00rKKap30). Hopefully someone knows how to solve this because I use this all the time.

Please let me know if there's some info missing or anything else that can be useful

I'm using Blender 3.0 but I also tested it in Blender 2.93 with the same result.

EDIT: Snapping behaviour works fine in edit mode

Comment: So basically you want to snap the object to a target's surface with the snapping object aligning its rotation with the target surface? CG Masters made a tutorial about that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gc8BekthXAQ I don't know if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately that doesn't solve the snapping issues.. it's more about the behaviour of the snapping than the alignment itself :/ It's a good way to align objects though.

Comment: Instead of rotating around the 3D cursor, what about moving the object? If you use the Snapping tool with Face snapping and the option "Align Rotation to Target" enabled, moving the object closer to another face should snap it there and align it (i.e. align the local Z axis of the moving object to the local Z axis of the face it snaps to).

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann thanks for your answer. It does align somewhat, but not really precise. However, this is not really the issue. It's the snapping behaviour that I want to solve.. I solved the alignment with a quick shrinkwrap.. fast and dirty but it worked... but I would like to know why the snapping works in a way in some files and in another way in other files :/ I'm sure it's a simple setting that I'm missing.. Thanks again for the answer!!

Comment: @mresala To explain why it behaves in one way or another depends a lot on which options you have enabled and if you are working in _Object Mode_ or _Edit Mode_. It's a bit tricky and unpredictable from time to time (at least in my eyes), but experimenting a lot with the different settings I got a feeling for how it works in most cases and which works best for me and my usual workflows.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann hey! yes, I know that it may be a bit unpredictable.. but I checked all the settings (available in the header) and they match those of the file where the snapping works as I expect.. I thought maybe there were more settings elsewhere that I don't know about... for example I have a startup file and there it works fine.. I uploaded a video to youtube if you want to check it out, and also to understand the expected behaviour: https://youtu.be/jOgT_sAVkFE Sorry, english is not my native language and I'm afraid I'm not being clear

Comment: Well, as I said before - I won't do it with rotate. What I see in your video different to my suggestion is: 1. You're rotating, not moving. 2. You don't have "Align Rotation to Target" enabled. If I do these two things it seems my result comes close to what you want to do. And talking about precision: the snapped face lies exactly flat on the target's face.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann thanks, but still.. I want to understand why I do one thing in one file and the same thing in another file and the result is different.. it's not about the alignment itself... it's about the snapping behaviour. Thanks anyway for taking the time :)